# fused type: undeclared name not builtin: double

Tags: cython

I'm trying to use Fused Types in my cython codes, but the double type can not be compiled. If I delete the double type from the fused type, compilation succeed. Why? thanks a lot.

python 3.6.4

cython 0.27.3

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter("ignore")

ctypedef np.float64_t DTYPE1_t
ctypedef np.int64_t DTYPE2_t

ctypedef fused number_or_arr:
    int
    np.ndarray
    double

def SUM(np.ndarray[DTYPE1_t, ndim=1] npdata,number_or_arr n):
    if n is double:
        print('it is double')
    elif n is int:
        print('it is int')
    elif n is np.ndarray:
        print('it is arr')
    return np.sum(npdata)


[z@localhost strafunc]$ python setuptest.py build_ext --inplace
running build_ext
cythoning ctest.pyx to ctest.c

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
    int
    np.ndarray
    double

def SUM(np.ndarray[DTYPE1_t, ndim=1] npdata,number_or_arr n):
    if n is double:
           ^
------------------------------------------------------------

ctest.pyx:16:12: undeclared name not builtin: double
building 'ctest' extension
gcc -pthread -B /home/z/anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/home/z/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/home/z/anaconda3/include/python3.6m -c ctest.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/ctest.o
ctest.c:1:2: error: #error Do not use this file, it is the result of a failed Cython compilation.
 #error Do not use this file, it is the result of a failed Cython compilation.
  ^
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation of fused types](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/fusedtypes.html#type-checking-specializations) gives these checks as:

```
if name_of_fused_type is double
```

not

```
if name_of_variable is double:
```

In your case it would be:

```
if number_or_arr is double:
```

(and then similar changes for the other two checks). The issue with your current version is that it's ambiguous - for the `int` case it could be asking to check if it's an `int` or it could be asking for a check that `n` is a Python type object exactly equal to the Python `int` type.

---

As an aside, I think it's going to be difficult to speed up "might be a number, might be an array" like this - you'd probably be best just to leave them untyped. Cython and arrays work best for speeding up indexing, which can't apply here (because it might be a number)

Comment: Thanks! I made a silly mistake. And you are right, it really cann't speed up here.